# update column by row number

Tags: mysql

I have one table that contain lots of records and I want to update my primary key by row number. My database is MySQL.

Comment: What is your question? What does your primary key look like right now?  What does it contain right now?

Comment: Do you run this update everytime you add a new row or delete a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't do that.
There is not a thing called "row number" in the database.
Such a number can be applicable only to output of certainly ordered and filtered data, but not to stored one.

Leave your primary key alone, it identifies the whole record, not it's "position" (especially because there is no position at all).

Why do you need that? Your task has another solution for sure, a proper one

Answer (score 0):

mysql isn't Oracle and doesn't support rownum.